# Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined range slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, interface

I have been trying to solve this problem regarding the Jquery UI Plugin. I'm trying to implement the range slider but it seems i always get this error in my google chrome browser

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/fix_zps412af2c4.png.

How can i fix this kind of problem

```
color.hook = function( hook ) {
var hooks = hook.split( " " );
each( hooks, function( i, hook ) {
    jQuery.cssHooks[ hook ] = {
        set: function( elem, value ) {
            var parsed, curElem,
                backgroundColor = "";

            if ( value !== "transparent" && ( jQuery.type( value ) !== "string" || ( parsed = stringParse( value ) ) ) ) {
                value = color( parsed || value );
                if ( !support.rgba && value._rgba[ 3 ] !== 1 ) {
                    curElem = hook === "backgroundColor" ? elem.parentNode : elem;
                    while (
                        (backgroundColor === "" || backgroundColor === "transparent") &&
                        curElem && curElem.style
                    ) {
                        try {
                            backgroundColor = jQuery.css( curElem, "backgroundColor" );
                            curElem = curElem.parentNode;
                        } catch ( e ) {
                        }
                    }

                    value = value.blend( backgroundColor && backgroundColor !== "transparent" ?
                        backgroundColor :
                        "_default" );
                }

                value = value.toRgbaString();
            }
            try {
                elem.style[ hook ] = value;
            } catch( e ) {
                // wrapped to prevent IE from throwing errors on "invalid" values like 'auto' or 'inherit'
            }
        }
    };
    jQuery.fx.step[ hook ] = function( fx ) {
        if ( !fx.colorInit ) {
            fx.start = color( fx.elem, hook );
            fx.end = color( fx.end );
            fx.colorInit = true;
        }
        jQuery.cssHooks[ hook ].set( fx.elem, fx.start.transition( fx.end, fx.pos ) );
    };
});

};
```

Comment: Please post your HTML, CSS, and javascript code, preferably in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not sure if i can post it at jsfiddle because i'm working at a magento site.